# Draggable Text Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a text editor that can be handled with drag and drop features of jQuery. I've been able to build draggable items, such as text box, image (placeholder for now), and to drop them in a sortable container; and to remove whatever element that is dropped trash bin or remove bar. However, the way drag and drop is executed looks somewhat awkward. 
For example, when I drag one draggable item out of its container, the container expands as I drag; and the way items in the container where draggable will be dropped is sorted looks a bit different than what I saw from other examples.
What can be done to fix these issues?
Does jQuery's draggable/sortable sound like a good tech to be used for this project?

Once I'm done with this issues, I'm planning to implement functionalities which allow users to pick the color, alignment for text, image sources - and ultimately voting feature.
Also, I want to be able to export whatever user build with the text editor to be saved in db and to be posted.
Can I get some good ideas as to how to approach to these?

I'm attaching jsFiddle and the code here.
Thank you very much for your help!

https://jsfiddle.net/WooS/907vzp09/

Snippet (click to open, is hidden for better visual):

```js
var elementID = "";
const textBox = "<input type=\"text\" class=\"draggable\" value=\"text...\">";
const imageBox = "<img class=\"img-fluid draggable\" src=\"http://placehold.it/300x200\" alt=\"\">";
const stickerBox = "<img class=\"img-fluid draggable\" src=\"http://placehold.it/50x50\" alt=\"\">";


$(document).ready(function(){
    //resizable and draggable text box
    $("#container").sortable({
        revert: true
    });

    //add textbox when dragging TEXT
    $("#textDrag").mousedown(function(){
        elementID = "text";
        console.log(elementID);
    });

    //add imagebox when dragging IMAGE
    $("#imageDrag").mousedown(function(){
        elementID = "image";
        console.log(elementID);
    });

    //add sticker when dragging STICKER
    $("#stickerDrag").mousedown(function(){
        elementID = "sticker";
        console.log(elementID);
    });

    //remove dropped elements
    $('#removeDrop').droppable({
        over: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    });

    $('.dragItem').draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#container",
        revert: "invalid",
        helper: function(){
            if(elementID=="text")
                return textBox;
            else if(elementID=="image")
                return imageBox;
            else
                return stickerBox;
        }
    });
})
```

```css
/* general layout styles */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.dragDrop {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.dragDrop a {
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dragDrop a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 20%;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}


/***************************************************/
/* dragDrop div elements styles */
.dragDrop div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.dragDrop div:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dragItem div {
    height: auto;
}

.dragItem {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


/***************************************************/
/* content div elements styles */
#container {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 30rem; 
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#subject{
    width: 100%;
}

.draggable{
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

input.draggable{
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 5rem;
}

#buttonContainer{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#removeDrop{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 7rem;
    text-align: center;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Draggable Side Bar -->
<div class="dragDrop bg-dark">
    <div draggable="true" class="dragItem" id="textDrag">
        <div>TEXT</div>
    </div>
    <div draggable="true" class="dragItem" id="imageDrag">
        <div>IMAGE</div>
    </div>
    <div draggable="true" class="dragItem" id="stickerDrag">
        <div>STICKER</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Content Space for Users -->
<div class="content">
    <div id="buttonContainer" class="btn-group-justified">
        <a href="article_list.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Back</a>
        <a href="article.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Post</a>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"/>
    <div id="container" class="ui-widget-content">
        <!--
            <input type="text" class="draggable" value="text...">
        -->
    </div>
    <div draggable="true" id="removeDrop" class="bg-dark">
        <div>REMOVE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/907vzp09/8/

Comment: Why not start with HTML5?